# How to get notified if the google shared drive reached maximum file count

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I keep on writing files to the shared drive and we need a way to get notified if the shared drive is full. Is there any google API available to get this information? How to track google shared drive?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Google Shared Drives have **no size limit** overall, and there is no API for querying a shared drive size.

### Shared Drive limits

Google Shared drives does not imply an overall size limit as is the case for  user drive that varies depending on the account type (Individual account, Google Workspace account, Business account...).

On the other hand, Shared Drive do have a limit on:

- The number of stored files: **400000**
- The maximum size of users uploads per day: 750 GB per file per user

You can refer to this [*Google Workspace Admin help*](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7338880?hl=en) page for more details on Shared Drives limits.

### EDIT (by @Jose Vasquez)

> In addition, there's an open [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154960927) in order to do so.
> If you find this is necessary I strongly recommend you to upvote this request as stated in [the *Google Drive API v3 - Missing Features* section](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/support#missing_features).

Comment: In addition, there's a feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154960927 open in order to do so. If you find this is necessary I strongly recommend you to upvote this request as stated in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/support#missing_features

Comment: Thanks @JoseVasquez for pointing that, I will add the link to the answer after your permission.

Comment: Yes of course !